# Was I being impolite using this phrase "Add our John Doe in the copy :)" at the end of a business conversation?

Tags: politeness, business-language, email

**Some context:** English is not my native language and I had a chat with my colleague from a remote location. She asked my team lead to add two users in some system and since the team lead was off the office that day, I had to help her. So the dialog went like this:

**She:** Thanks John Doe! Have they also been added to Fake System?

**Me:** Hi Sara Connor,
John is out of office today. I will have a look.
If they are not added, should I add them?

**She:** Yes, please. Thanks Alex!

**Me:** I had a look - they have not been added. Unfortunately, we don't have the rights to add new users.
To do this there is a formal procedure:
Please send an email to some@fake.email with request and description of what needs to be done (usernames/permissions to create)

**She:** Thanks Alex! I'll email them.

**She:** Hi Alex - Sorry to bother you again, I'm getting an Outlook notification that the some@fake.email address is no longer valid. Is there a new address or process?

**Me:** Sorry, I have given you the wrong one.
The correct is - someother@fake.email

**She:** Perfect. Thanks!

**Me:** Add our John Doe in the copy :)

And I got a comment from one of my colleagues:
*I am not sure that you phrase is really polite

It is imperative "add..."(it is an order), and it is unclear meaning of "our"*

It got me confused, because technically it looks like he's right, but I feel that what I wrote was perfectly OK. Or am I mistaken and this last phrase can really be considered rude/impolite and might have offended the recipient?

Comment: I'm no expert.  But I have a strong opinion.  Technically, you made a statement that demanded her to 'Add our John Doe'.  But in today's day and age, I find it arrogant for people speaking a language natively to expect a non-native speaker to navigate such nuances.  Two things going for you, one, you used a smiley face.  Two, you don't speak English natively.  As for what is "Right" or "Wrong", you did **Nothing** wrong.  But this is your work and you must navigate other people's emotions as well.  So despite the truth of who was right or wrong, If I were you, I'd offer a simple apology.

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks for your comment, it's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sentence does sound a little imperative. But there is a fix. You can add the word 'Please' to the sentence and it turns from command to request.

For example :

"Add John Doe in the copy."

"Please, add John Doe in the copy."